# Python: Looping through a tuple, first element is incorrect

Tags: python, tuples, enumerate

I apologise if I missed an answer to this question. I am looping through a tuple in Python using enumerate and simply calling each element of a tuple. For the first element, only if it is == 1, the secon method returns 2 instead of 1. All other elements are displayed correctly

```
tup = (1,2,2,3,4,5)
for el in enumerate(tup):
    print(el[1])
for el in tup:
    print(tup[el])
```

The loop using enumerate returns correct results:
1
2
2
3
4
5

But the second loop returns:
2
2
2
3
4
5

This only happens, if the first element is 1 O_o.

Comment: In the second loop, you are indexing... `tup[1]`, `tup[2]`, ... == second_element, third_element, so on...

Comment: You are asking why do you get different results?

Comment: @Bogda Doicin Yes

Answer (score 3):

You should print `el` in the second loop.

```
tup = (1,2,2,3,4,5)
for el in enumerate(tup):
    print(el[1])
for el in tup:
    print(el)
```

otherwise in the first loop `tup[el]` will print the second element. `el` has a value of `1` in the first loop so `tup[el] = tup[1] = 2`

Comment: So how come if the tup = (3,2,2,3,4,5), both loops return the same result?

Comment: With `enumerate` it's logical. Because again the tup[1] is 2